# facing a problem while learning ternary operator in c#

Tags: c#

i am using this code of ternary operator but facing error of red lines.

```
using System;

namespace ternoryoperator
{
    public class Ternory_Operator
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Name");
            string Name1 = Console.ReadLine();
            string Name2 = "N/A";

            Name1 == "asdf" ? Console.WriteLine(Name2) : Console.WriteLine(Name1);

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

> Blockquote
>
> Blockquote

Comment: `error of red lines`... - you should consider to learn reading errors - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/error-list-window?view=vs-2017

Comment: Or this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/find-and-fix-code-errors?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator can only be used with expressions that return a value. `Console.WriteLine()` does not. You also have to assign the returned value to a variable or use it in another expression. Try this instead:

```
var result = Name1 == "asdf" ? Name2 : Name1;
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: A note to add that C#7 allows exception expressions as well.  `var result = Name1 == "asdf" ? Name2 : throw new Exception("...");`

Answer (score 0):

*Ternary operator* is not an if..else statement, but rather an operator. It isn't meant to execute method, but it returns value, left value if an expression is true, right value if false.

```
expression ? leftValue : rightValue
```

It of course can execute method if such method returns a value that can be returned by *ternary operator*, which is not a case for `Console.WriteLine()` - this method returns `void`.

So in your case you have to either save result of ternary operator to a variable and use this variable:

```
var name = Name1 == "asdf" ? Name2 : Name1;
Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Or use ternary operator inside method call:

```
Console.WriteLine(Name1 == "asdf" ? Name2 : Name1);
```